# Python twisted, reactor.callLater() not defering

Tags: twisted

The following code snippet is from a python poker server. The program works except when trying to delay the start of a tourney when a reactor.callLater is used.

The variable "wait" gets its integer from an xml file which has a setting of "60". However the delay is never implemented and the tourney always starts immediately.  I am not very familiar with python or twisted just trying to hack this into working for me.  One thing however from my perspective is it seems that it shouldn't work given that I can't see how or where the variable "old_state" gets its value in order for the code to properly determine the states of the server. But perhaps I am mistaken.

I hope that someone familiar with python and twisted can see what the problem might be and be willing to enlighten me on this issue.

```
elif old_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_REGISTERING and new_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_RUNNING:
    self.databaseEvent(event = PacketPokerMonitorEvent.TOURNEY_START, param1 = tourney.serial)            
    reactor.callLater(0.01, self.tourneyBroadcastStart, tourney.serial)
    # Only obey extra_wait_tourney_start if we had been registering and are now running,
    # since we only want this behavior before the first deal.
    wait = int(self.delays.get('extra_wait_tourney_start', 0))
    if wait > 0:
        reactor.callLater(wait, self.tourneyDeal, tourney)
    else:
        self.tourneyDeal(tourney)
```

For reference I have placed the larger portion of the code that is relative to the problem.

```
def spawnTourneyInCore(self, tourney_map, tourney_serial, schedule_serial, currency_serial, prize_currency):
    tourney_map['start_time'] = int(tourney_map['start_time'])
    if tourney_map['sit_n_go'] == 'y':
        tourney_map['register_time'] = int(seconds()) - 1
    else:
        tourney_map['register_time'] = int(tourney_map.get('register_time', 0))
    tourney = PokerTournament(dirs = self.dirs, **tourney_map)
    tourney.serial = tourney_serial
    tourney.verbose = self.verbose
    tourney.schedule_serial = schedule_serial
    tourney.currency_serial = currency_serial
    tourney.prize_currency = prize_currency
    tourney.bailor_serial = tourney_map['bailor_serial']
    tourney.player_timeout = int(tourney_map['player_timeout'])
    tourney.via_satellite = int(tourney_map['via_satellite'])
    tourney.satellite_of = int(tourney_map['satellite_of'])
    tourney.satellite_of, reason = self.tourneySatelliteLookup(tourney)
    tourney.satellite_player_count = int(tourney_map['satellite_player_count'])
    tourney.satellite_registrations = []
    tourney.callback_new_state = self.tourneyNewState
    tourney.callback_create_game = self.tourneyCreateTable
    tourney.callback_game_filled = self.tourneyGameFilled
    tourney.callback_destroy_game = self.tourneyDestroyGame
    tourney.callback_move_player = self.tourneyMovePlayer
    tourney.callback_remove_player = self.tourneyRemovePlayer
    tourney.callback_cancel = self.tourneyCancel
    if not self.schedule2tourneys.has_key(schedule_serial):
        self.schedule2tourneys[schedule_serial] = []
    self.schedule2tourneys[schedule_serial].append(tourney)
    self.tourneys[tourney.serial] = tourney
    return tourney

def deleteTourney(self, tourney):
    if self.verbose > 2:
        self.message("deleteTourney: %d" % tourney.serial)
    self.schedule2tourneys[tourney.schedule_serial].remove(tourney)
    if len(self.schedule2tourneys[tourney.schedule_serial]) <= 0:
        del self.schedule2tourneys[tourney.schedule_serial]
    del self.tourneys[tourney.serial]

def tourneyResumeAndDeal(self, tourney):
    self.tourneyBreakResume(tourney)
    self.tourneyDeal(tourney)

def tourneyNewState(self, tourney, old_state, new_state):
    cursor = self.db.cursor()
    updates = [ "state = '" + new_state + "'" ]
    if old_state != TOURNAMENT_STATE_BREAK and new_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_RUNNING:
        updates.append("start_time = %d" % tourney.start_time)
    sql = "update tourneys set " + ", ".join(updates) + " where serial = " + str(tourney.serial)
    if self.verbose > 2:
        self.message("tourneyNewState: " + sql)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    if cursor.rowcount != 1:
        self.error("modified %d rows (expected 1): %s " % ( cursor.rowcount, sql ))
    cursor.close()
    if new_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_BREAK:
        # When we are entering BREAK state for the first time, which
        # should only occur here in the state change operation, we
        # send the PacketPokerTableTourneyBreakBegin.  Note that this
        # code is here and not in tourneyBreakCheck() because that
        # function is called over and over again, until the break
        # finishes.  Note that tourneyBreakCheck() also sends a
        # PacketPokerGameMessage() with the time remaining, too.
        secsLeft = tourney.remainingBreakSeconds()
        if secsLeft == None:
            # eek, should I really be digging down into tourney's
            # member variables in this next assignment?
            secsLeft = tourney.breaks_duration
        resumeTime = seconds() + secsLeft
        for gameId in map(lambda game: game.id, tourney.games):
            table = self.getTable(gameId)
            table.broadcast(PacketPokerTableTourneyBreakBegin(game_id = gameId, resume_time = resumeTime))
        self.tourneyBreakCheck(tourney)
    elif old_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_BREAK and new_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_RUNNING:
        wait = int(self.delays.get('extra_wait_tourney_break', 0))
        if wait > 0:
            reactor.callLater(wait, self.tourneyResumeAndDeal, tourney)
        else:
            self.tourneyResumeAndDeal(tourney)
    elif old_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_REGISTERING and new_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_RUNNING:
        self.databaseEvent(event = PacketPokerMonitorEvent.TOURNEY_START, param1 = tourney.serial)            
        reactor.callLater(0.01, self.tourneyBroadcastStart, tourney.serial)
        # Only obey extra_wait_tourney_start if we had been registering and are now running,
        # since we only want this behavior before the first deal.
        wait = int(self.delays.get('extra_wait_tourney_start', 0))
        if wait > 0:
            reactor.callLater(wait, self.tourneyDeal, tourney)
        else:
            self.tourneyDeal(tourney)
    elif new_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_RUNNING:
        self.tourneyDeal(tourney)
    elif new_state == TOURNAMENT_STATE_BREAK_WAIT:
        self.tourneyBreakWait(tourney)
```

Comment: Please try to reduce this problem down to a [simple, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org) so that potential answerers can run your code and see what's going on.  There are lots of potential problems which could create this issue, and with only code fragments to go on, I could only guess at what those issues are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that this code has several imported files that were in another directory that I did not examine.  I also made a false assumption of the purpose of this code block.  I expected the function to be arbitrary and delay each tourney by n seconds but in practice it implements the delay only when a player forgets about the game and does not show up for it. These facts were made clear once I examined the proper files. Lesson learned.  Look at all the imports!